# MySQL DATE_ADD INTERVAL is not working with Hibernate.

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql, intervals

My query below, shows hibernate exception:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(MIN(t.time),'%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 6 DAY) FROM Table t;
```

From what I understand, hibernate doesn't recognize `INTERVAL` keyword.

Can anyone please help me write an HQL query which gives me the same result as my above query?

(I am trying to get the date post 1 week from the minimum date in my table)

Answer (score 1):

HQL and SQL are two different things. You could use a native SQL query instead of a HQL query. Or you could just execute the following query:

```
select min(t.time) from SomeEntity e
```

and add 6 days in Java:

```
Date minDate = (Date) query.uniqueResult();
minDate = DateUtils.addDays(d, 6); // using apache commons-lang
```

Comment: I need the result inside my query, because i am using it as a sub-query.

I am trying to find some cumulative value of a row in my table only for the first week. So, inside my query there are condition like:

date >= min(date)
and
date <= (a date after 6 days from the min(date))

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll need to use SQL.